# How do I pass a function for the breaks in ggplot when I need to pass arguments besides the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write a function in R that takes in a data frame with three variables: an independent variable, a dependent variable, and a grouping variable and then plotting each group separately using facet_wrap.  I'm running into an issue where the variables have noticeably different ranges depending on the group and I would like to have different breaks in the x and y axis for each group.  At the same time the function I wrote to generate the vector of breaks needs to take the number of plots on each axis (rows and columns of plots in facet_wrap) so the number of breaks can be reduced as the number of plots on the page increase.

I can pass a function to scale_x_continuous to generate the breaks and limits but cannot give the function any arguments aside from the data argument it takes.  This gives a plot with good breaks for each individual graph but the axis breaks get too clustered when there are too many graphs on a page.  Is there a way to pass some arguments to a breaks function while still having the function only operate on a single group?

Examples below:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Breaks Function ----
f <- function(x,
              nplots = 1){
  range <- seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), nplots)
}
#Dummy Data Creation ----
set.seed(225)
NewX1 <- seq(1, 10, 1)
NewX2 <- seq(2, 20, 2)
NewX <- append(NewX1, NewX2)

NewY1 <- rnorm(10, 10, 1)
NewY2 <- rnorm(10, 20, 1)
NewY <- append(NewY1, NewY2)

NewGroupvar1 <- rep("A", 10) 
NewGroupvar2 <- rep("B", 10)
NewGroupvar <- append(NewGroupvar1, NewGroupvar2)

NewData <- data.frame(NewX, NewY, NewGroupvar)

#Test Plots ----
#Gives breaks based on group but does not take the nplots argument
```

```
ggplot(data = NewData, mapping = aes(x = NewX, y = NewY)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = f,
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~NewGroupvar,
             nrow = 1,
             ncol = 2,
             scales = 'free')
```

[image]
#Takes the nplots argument but does not compute the breaks for each level in the grouping variable

```
ggplot(data = NewData, mapping = aes(x = NewX, y = NewY)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(x = NewX, nplots = 2),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~NewGroupvar,
             nrow = 1,
             ncol = 2,
             scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output to be in this case? I'm not sure what needs to be different in this case. Maybe you want a function that returns a function? Like `f2 <- function(nplots = 1){function(x) seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)), nplots)}` Then you can use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = f2(), expand = c(0, 0))` or `scale_x_continuous(breaks = f2(nplots = 2), expand = c(0, 0))`

Comment: @MrFlick That should work.  I want two graphs side by side that have breaks that are dependent on the nplots argument and the range of the data at that particular factor level.